# Abbreviate words in a string to comply with max length

Tags: python, string, data-manipulation

I have a vector of strings (phrases with several words).
For reasons out of the scope of this question I need to comply with a length limit of N characters per string.

The very first thing I thought was to splice each string, but unfortunately the result of the operation will be facing end user (the end users will have to read the truncated strings and make sense out of them).

That means that I can't just slice the strings, because if I did so the following:

```
This is a simple test with FOO
This is a simple test with BAR
```

will be converted to

```
This is a simple te...
This is a simple te...
```

Meaning that data will be lost and the users won't be able to distinguish between the two strings.

After thinking a little bit more I figured out the best possible solution is to abbreviate as little characters of as little words as possible, always in accordance with the max length constraint.

With such a behaviour the previous example would be converted to

```
This is a sim. te. with FOO
This is a sim. te. with BAR
```

I figured out I'll ask here for an alternative/better solution, before coding this.
Also, if there isn't any better alternative, what things should I keep in mind while implementing this? Can you give me any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I have a few thoughts... which may or may not meet your needs. To begin, here are some additional [forms of abbreviation](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/12910) that you may be able to programatically implement.

**Remove Vowels**

If you remove vowels, you may be able to abbreviate words within the desired lengths, and be slightly more readable. Removing vowels is an [acceptable form](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110905/general-rules-for-creating-abbreviations) of abbreviation. Keep in mind, you will need to keep the first and last letter of the word even if they are vowels. organization = orgnztn

**Use Abbreviation API**

https://Abbreviations.com has an API with abbreviations. This might be useful for abbreviating longer words. For example, to find the abbreviation of "organization": https://www.abbreviations.com/abbreviation/organization abbreviates as ORG

It appears this user has [attempted to do this](https://pypi.org/project/abbreviate/) in python. If you know you will have frequent phrases, you can create a dictionary of the abbreviated form.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no matter where you truncate the data, there is a chance that two strings will end up looking the same to the end user. You could do some string comparison to determine where the differences are, then write some logic to truncate characters in other locations.